# SFTP: how to know if i'm connecting to a unix or windows host?

Tags: java, windows, unix, sftp

i have created an internal library to make generic FTPs or SFTPs using apache-commons and JSCH libs

When i upload text files from windows to unix i can switch to ASCII mode if i'm using FTP, but this is not posible with SFTP protocol, so i make a custom inputstream reader which take care of the CRLF vs CR windows/unix end line problem.

Now my concern if  there is a method to know if the SFTP host is Windows or Unix, in which case i encapsulate the FileInputStreamReader whith my custom Windows2UnixInputStreamReader.

Do you know a methos to know the SO of the host? preferably if solution is througth the FTP/SFTP connection

Comment: Isn't it enough to ask remote end to use your custom input reader? If you intend to use your library for unattended (w/o human operator) FTP transfers, simplest way seems to have some database of participating hosts with their respective OSes.

Comment: i'm triying to make a generic lib to handle FTP/SFTP whith the minimal config: HOST, USER, PASS, PORT

Comment: Your question tells precisely that _generic_ library will need to know at least types of local and remote OSes. Putting functionality of OS fingerprinting into _generic FTP_ library is an inappropriate thing.

Comment: I want that the library detects the local and remote OS and handle them correctly, this is not an inapropiate thing

Comment: fine, I just wanted to hint that FTP transfer and OS fingerprinting have nothing in common, so putting them together in one library may be deemed slightly off. If you want, you can put OS fingerprinting in another _generic OS fingerprinting library_, and distribute both of them together. But, of course, it's up to you.

Answer (score 3):

There is a number of possible ways to complete your task, however I'm not sure if your libraries support them:

- SFTP protocol contains SSH_FXF_TEXT_MODE file open flag, allowing to
  open file in text mode, translating EOL sequences to CRLF (available
  since version 6 of protocol, AFAIR).
- 'newline' SFTP extension - it tells exact server's EOL convention
- Parsing SSH server software/version string.

Comment: do you know if JSCH lib has a method to extract de newline delimiter? with it i can know for sure if i'm in windows or unix enviroment

Comment: Their ChannelSftp has .getExtension method, you should see if 'newline' extension is available there. Also it can have other names. And, not every server sends it.

Comment: Not lucky on this server. tried newline, Newline, newLine and NewLine

Comment: JSCH is opensource - you can put breakpoint in ChannelSftp.Start and see what extensions it receives. Probably it is named like newline@openssh.com, whatever else.

Comment: in debug mode the hastable which stores the extensions only has posix-rename@openssh.com, statvfs@openssh.com and fstatvfs@openssh.com. Maybe i have to resign

Comment: Why resign, you didn't try everything possible yet :) You can also get getServerVersion() , it will contain software name, and depending on software name set line ending to LF or CRLF.

Comment: The server version is SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2 can i deduce i'm connecting to a unix/windows system  based on this?

Comment: Most likely it is unix system, I don't know about good OpenSSH ports to Windows since 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 100% solution because FTP protocol does not depend on platform. However you can use heuristics. FTP allows to get list of directories, so you can try to get list of files under well known root and try to base you conclusion on the results.

This method however is not 100% because the root of FTP server is not necessarily the root of file system, so you can fail to find any well known files or directories under this root.

Probably better way to discover Operating system of target host is using tools like [nmap](http://nmap.org/book/man-os-detection.html).

Comment: He doesn't have problem with FTP since it allows text mode transfer, the problem is with SFTP, which didn't allow text mode transfer till version 6 of protocol.